# How to solve $\:\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x$ type of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So how to solve the differential equation $\:\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x$.?

I know how to solve normal differential equation such as:$\:\frac{dx}{dt}=x$, but the  above is new to me. I suppose how can I integrate for $x$ when we have $\:\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

Note I am trying to derive the equation of simple harmonic motion.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#:~:text=In%20mechanics%20and%20physics%2C%20simple,towards%20the%20object's%20equilibrium%20position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#:%7E:text=In%20mechanics%20and%20physics%2C%20simple,towards%20the%20object%27s%20equilibrium%20position).

Comment: This may be of help https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations

Comment: Let $x=r \cdot e^{i\theta}$. And then it is a simple equation for which you can solve for $\theta$. Also use the identity $\omega^2$ to make a simplification.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x'$ and integrate to reduce the order.of the differential equation.

Comment: @Aryadeva Hello sir, thanks for commenting. Do you mind showing how its done, a sneak peak will do? I tried it, but my working seems off. Many thanks.

Comment: yes $x''x'+k/m x'x=0 $ $ \implies (x'^2)'+k/m (x^2)'=0 $ integrate Nina. $x'^2+k/mx^2=c_1$  Then it's a first order differential equation.  It's separable....separate x and t and integrate again and you're done.

Comment: I added some line sin my answer Nina I hope it's more clear now

Comment: The thing I have done is in spirit the same thing. It is just a more special case to solve if any initial position is already given.

Answer (score 3):

$$\:\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x$$
Is a second order linear differential equation. You need the characteristic polynomial. I suppose $\dfrac km >0$:
$$r^2+\dfrac k m =0$$
Solve that equation then the solution is :
$$x(t)=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$$
That you can write as:
$$x(t)=c_1\cos{(r_1t)}+c_2\sin{(r_2t)}$$
where $r_1,r_2 (r_1 \ne r_2)$ are solutions of the characteristic polynomial.

---

You can aslo multiply by $x'$ both sides and reduce the order of the DE:
$$x''x'+\frac km xx'=0$$
$$(x'^2)'+\frac{k}{m}(x^2)'=0$$
Integrate:
$$x'^2+\frac{k}{m}x^2=c_1$$
it's a first order differential equation that is separable.
$$\dfrac {dx}{dt}=\pm \sqrt {c_1-\frac{k}{m}x^2}$$
Separate and integrate again.

Comment: how did you find the char. polynomial.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi for a second order linear differential equation  $ y''+ay'+by=0$ the characteristic polynomial is simply $r^2+ar+b=0$

Comment: I am well aware of that, and I know that they are guess-work ($e^{r x}$), I wanted you to include the part where you told let the solution be of form e^something x

Comment: I see what you mean @AnindyaPrithvi

Answer (score 2):

Given that $a=\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\dfrac{k}{m}x$

Let $\frac{k}{m}=\omega^2$. Here $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

$$a=-\omega^2 x \implies \frac{dv}{dt}=-\omega^2x \implies \dfrac{dv}{dx} \cdot \dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\omega^2x \implies \int_{0}^{v} v \cdot dv=\int_{A}^{x}-\omega^2 x \cdot dx \\ \implies  v= \pm \omega \cdot \sqrt{A^2-x^2}$$

Where $A$ is amplitude or the maximum displacement of the block or object from the initial position.

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\pm \omega \sqrt{A^2-x^2} \implies \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}=\pm \omega \cdot dt$$

The rest is trivial. The above integral is a standard one. Or you can solve it using the substitution $x=A \sin u$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a question, why did you take $x$ to $A$ in  $\int _A^x-\omega ^2\:x\:\cdot \:dx$

Comment: You can take any point as your initial position. Because the velocity at the extreme position is 0, I took $x=A$.